# Difference between preloader and splash screen in java

Tags: java, javafx, splash-screen, preloader

I was wondering what are the **specific** differences between [**preloader**](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/Preloader.html) and **splash screen** in java. It seems to me that both the features gives the same output (i.e. holding the attention of the end user while loading the main application) but have different technique and system to implement.

Theoretically the **specific differences** between them would help a lot. TIA.

Comment: Please note: you should consider if the answers you receive are resolving your problem; if so, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are talking about JavaFx ... this [document](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/deploy_user_experience.htm#BABFIECI) from Oracle states that:

- Initially there is a splash screen; so that would be the very first panel shown to the user; right after startup; to let him know that something is going on
- And then some time later, the JavaFx is turning into "preparation" mode ... including the "preload" stuff

Of course, depending on your context; there might be other definitions. Back in the good old days of AWT or Swing; one would implement a splash screen completely by himself (and for example try to **only** use AWT components to do that; to avoid the noticeable delay that kicks in when using Swing components to achieve the very same thing).